# Can the full image of an X11 window be grab using the window id with the window is covered by another

Tags: x11

I want to capture the image of an X11 window, using its window id.
But it fails when the window(WinA) is covered by another window(WinB), the image I captured is combined by partial WinA and WinB just as the way I can see on the screen.
Is there any method to ignore the coverage of the window, so that I can get the full image no matter the window is covered or not.
Maybe set some property of the WinA?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoth the fine manual:

> If the window has backing-store, the backing-store contents are returned for regions of the window that are obscured by noninferior windows. If the window does not have backing-store, the returned contents of such obscured regions are undefined.

So you need to set up the BackingStore window attribute.

Comment: or call "NameWindowPixmap" request from Composite extension - see http://linux.die.net/man/3/xcompositenamewindowpixmap